# How to correctly reshape the multiclass output of predict_proba of a sklearn classifier?

Tags: python, numpy, scikit-learn, classification, multilabel-classification

I have a multiclass problem with 10 classes.
Using any of the sklearn classifiers with predict_proba I get an output of

```
(n_classes, n_samples, n_classes_probability_1_or_0)
```

in my case `(10, 4789, 2)`

Now with binary Classification I would just do

```
model.predict_proba(X)[:, 1]
```

I had assumed that:

```
pred = np.array(model.predict_proba(X))
pred = pred.reshape(-1, 10, 2)[:, :, 1]
```

would do the same, but the ordering is completely off.

Now `y[:, class]` corresponds to `pred[class, :, 1]`

I know I'm thinking of the shape the wrong way, but unfortunately I can't see.

How do I reshape it correctly?
The goal is to use it in the roc_auc_score metrics
and I want to have a shape of `(instances, classes_probabilities = 1)`

Could you help please?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It would be useful if you mention that you are using `MultiOutputClassifier` because most classifiers for multiclass in scikit learn don't return something like yours, so using an example dataset:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.multioutput import MultiOutputClassifier
from sklearn import preprocessing

lb = preprocessing.LabelBinarizer()

from sklearn.datasets import make_classification
X, y = make_classification(n_samples=500,n_classes=10,n_informative=10,n_clusters_per_class=1)
y = lb.fit_transform(y)
```

Set up classifier

```
forest = RandomForestClassifier(n_estimators=10, random_state=1)
model = MultiOutputClassifier(forest, n_jobs=-1)
model.fit(X, y)
```

You don't need to think about reshaping it, simply pull out the values:

```
pred = np.array(model.predict_proba(X))
```

Like you have done before, this will correspond to every row being a class, every column being your observation:

```
pred[:,:,1].shape
(10, 500)
```

To get your probabilities, just transpose:

```
prob1 = pred[:,:, 1].T

prob1[:2]
array([[0.9, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
       [0.1, 0. , 0.1, 0. , 0.7, 0. , 0.1, 0. , 0.1, 0. ]])
```

Compare with if we actually extract it and stack:

```
prob2 = np.hstack([i[:,1].reshape(-1,1) for i in model.predict_proba(X)])
array([[0.9, 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. , 0. ],
   [0.1, 0. , 0.1, 0. , 0.7, 0. , 0.1, 0. , 0.1, 0. ]])
```